# Laravel models with multiple relationships not acting as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `User` model and an `Organization` model which I'm trying to relate to one another.

The `users` table has `id` and `current_organization_id` (foreign key) fields (among the other normal fields).

The `organizations` table has `id` and `owner_id` (foreign key) fields (along with some other data fields).

There is also a pivot table, `organization_user` which links the two via their respective `id`.

My models are set up like this:

User:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends \Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

  use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'users';

  /**
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

  /**
   * Defining many to many relationship to organizations
   */
  public function organizations()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization');
  }

  /**
   * Defining relationship to current selected organization
   */
  public function current_organization()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('Organization');
  }

}
```

Organization:

```
<?php

class Organization extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [];

  public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('User');
  }

  public function owner()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}
```

The idea is that a single organization is owned by a user, but an organization has many users, and each user has a "current" organization, which they can select from any organization that they belong to.

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to do `$user->current_organization->id` I get a `Trying to get property of non-object` error, and if I try `$user->current_organization()->id;` I get a `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$id` error.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong that I can't retrieve the `current_organization` like I'm trying to do above?

EDIT:

I'm thinking it has to do with my `hasOne` relationship, but I tried doing this:

```
public function current_organization()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Organization', 'id', 'current_organization_id');
}
```

and still nothing. `$user->current_organization;` is returning `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging and searching, I came across [this post](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12383) which led me to the real problem -- the underscore in the function name.

From the link:

> The Eloquent docs mention "keep in mind that the methods should follow
>   camel-casing, even though your database columns are snake-case."  So I
>   believe the function name should be "objectMinor()".  Eloquent
>   actually converts the snake-case column names to camel-case for the
>   method names.  This is a bit confusing, but it does it to conform to
>   PHP naming conventions.

So, using @Cryode answer and the above, I came up with:

```
public function currentOrganization()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Organization', 'current_organization_id');
}
```

Which can be called via:

```
$organization = $user->current_organization;
```

I think they should really make this more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a `belongsTo` relationship for the current organization.

```
public function current_organization()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Organization', 'current_organization_id');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still returning `NULL`. And I double checked just to make sure, and `$user->current_organization_id` is retuning `1`, and `Organization::find($user->current_organization_id)` is returning the correct organization. Any other ideas?